# How to deploy GWT application with pretty compiled HTML using google plugin for Eclipse

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt

I use google plugin for eclipse to deploy my GWT application, it works good until now, the deploy action first compiles my GWT project with "obfuscated" output style, now i want it change to "Pretty" because i have to debug the client side on the fly, i just can't see the obfuscated stack.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is simple, first open "GWT compile" dialog, select Detailed or Pretty, click apply, close the dialog, then it will be deployed with Detailed or Pretty style.

Comment: thanks for this.   But does that setting also change what goes up to the server when I do a deploy?

Answer (score 13):

Compiler level is part of the GWT compiler options :

```xml
-style Script output style: OBF[USCATED], PRETTY, or DETAILED (defaults to OBF)
```

**If you're using Ant :**

modify your build.xml file :

```xml
<arg value="-style"/>
<arg value="pretty"/>
```

**If you're using Maven :**

modify your pom.xml file :

```xml
<plugin>
<groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
<artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.4.0</version>
<executions>
    <execution>
        <goals>
            <goal>compile</goal>
        </goals>
        </execution>
</executions>
<configuration>
    <style>PRETTY</style>
    <!-- OTHER STUFF -->
</configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, your way did works, however my situation is using google plugin eclipse to deploy my application, not Ant or Maven. I found the solution, and will answer my own question below.

Comment: My bad, when you create an app without any IDE, Google rely on a Ant script. I wasn't aware that the plugin for eclipse could also manage all by his own.

Comment: For ant <arg line="-style pretty"/> is more succinct.