# changing the obfuscation level of GWT code

Tags: gwt

I am trying to use the flag;

`-style PRETTY`
as discussed here:
http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/FAQ_DebuggingAndCompiling.html

however its not obvious to me where I place that setting.
I'm looking to send the 'PRETTY' code up to a parallel version on my live server.

I deploy directly from my IDE (Eclipse)

does it live in my .gwt.xml file?

thanks for any tips.

Comment: I guess the answer is here, trying now http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12746059/how-to-deploy-gwt-application-with-pretty-compiled-html-using-google-plugin-for

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to deploy GWT application with pretty compiled HTML using google plugin for Eclipse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12746059/how-to-deploy-gwt-application-with-pretty-compiled-html-using-google-plugin-for)

Answer (score 3):

If you use maven you can place it in your `.pom` file to not obfuscate the transpiled JS:

```
<properties>
    <gwt.compiler.style>PRETTY</gwt.compiler.style>
</properties>
```

For not obfuscating the CSS, use:

```
<set-configuration-property name="CssResource.style" value="PRETTY"/>
```

in your `*.gwt.xml`

Comment: thanks, but I'm not using maven just standard gwt.xml files.  Will that properties flag work directly in my *.gwt.xml files?

Comment: It's and option for the GWT compiler. So you have to add it to your build script or whatever you use.

Comment: okay thanks.  I get that its a compiler option - but I just use deploy from my IDE (Eclipse) so it's not at all obvious where I'm supposed to set the option sadly.  (doesn't work if I try to put these options in my *.gwt.xml files )

Comment: Okay, that seems to be an important information for the question :-) Maybe have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12746059/how-to-deploy-gwt-application-with-pretty-compiled-html-using-google-plugin-for